# intergral of lim inf and lim sup

Tags: measure-theory

Let $(f_n)$ be a sequence of numerical measurable functions on some measurable space and assume that there exists some $\mu$-intergrable $g$ such that for all $n\in\mathbb N$ the inequality $|f_n|\leq g$ holds. We know that $$\int \liminf _{n\to \infty} f_n d\mu\leq  \liminf _{n\to \infty}\int f_n d\mu\leq \limsup_{n\to \infty}\int f_n d\mu\leq \int \limsup_{n\to \infty} f_n d\mu$$ Provide an explicit example where this chian fails to hold because such $g$ does not exist. Does anyone have a hint for me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The left-most inequality holds by applying Fatou's lemma to $g + f_n \ge 0$. If there is no majorant this could fail. For instance, take $f_n = - \chi_{[n,n+1]}$ on the line with Lebesgue measure. Then $$\int \liminf_{n \to \infty} f_n \, dx = 0$$ but $$\liminf_{n \to \infty} \int f_n \, dx = -1.$$

The middle inequality is always valid.

The right-most inequality holds by applying Fatou's lemma to $g - f_n \ge 0$. Again if there is no majorant this could fail. For instance, take $f_n = \chi_{[n,n+1]}$ on the line with Lebesgue measure. Then $$\int \limsup_{n \to \infty} f_n \, dx = 0$$ but $$\limsup_{n \to \infty} \int f_n \, dx = 1.$$